# Is asking several sub-questions in one question permissible?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

It's a fairly straightforward question. Instead of opening, say, 5 questions for a very similar topic, is it permissible to ask multiple questions in a single question? Not only is this helpful for the asker, but also collects related information to a variety of questions about a fairly specific topic in a single place for the reader.

Answer (score 4):

It will depend very much on what the questions are and how you define "very similar".  I don't think it's possible to give an exact answer yes/no answer.

Consider the following (fictional) examples:

> I'm building this super 555 timer circuit I found online!
>
> - How can I work out where pin 1 is on the 555?
> - What should the value of R1 be for a delay of 10 seconds?
> - Can I power it from a 9V battery instead of 2 AA batteries?
> - Why is there a capacitor across Vcc and GND?  I don't have any, can I leave this out?
> - I want to replace the LED with a 1W Cree bulb, will this work?

All of these are tenuously "related" to the same circuit but I'd suggest there are too many discrete concepts for a good question.

However something like:

> I'm building this tuned circuit and I don't understand how C1 and L1 work.
>
> - How can I calculate the value of the capacitor?
> - If I change the capacitor, what effect will that have on the inductor?

In this example there are two individual questions but they are very closely related.  The answer to one directly references the answer to the other.  I suggest this sort of multiple question is fine.